# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: myCSharpDemoCalc\work\MyCSharpDemoCalc.j4n.dll

Tags: c#, java, jni4net

jni4net does not generate MyCSharpDemoCalc.j4n.dll. generateProxy says it does but the file does not get created. Hence, I get System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Is this a bug in jni4net? I am using version 0.8.6.0

```
D:\Temp\jni4net\samples\myCSharpDemoCalc>generateProxies
..\..\lib\jni4net-LGPL-3.0.txt
..\..\lib\jni4net.j-0.8.6.0.jar
..\..\lib\jni4net.n-0.8.6.0.dll
..\..\lib\jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.6.0.dll
..\..\lib\jni4net.n.w32.v40-0.8.6.0.dll
..\..\lib\jni4net.n.w64.v20-0.8.6.0.dll
..\..\lib\jni4net.n.w64.v40-0.8.6.0.dll
    7 file(s) copied.
jni4net.proxygen - Copyright (C) 2009 Pavel Savara - licensed under GPLv3
will generate JVM mycsharpdemocalc.icalc
will generate JVM mycsharpdemocalc.democalc
proxygen done
compile classes
MyCSharpDemoCalc.j4n.jar
MyCSharpDemoCalc.j4n.dll
csc: file `/nologo' does not exist
compiling usage

D:\Temp\jni4net\samples\myCSharpDemoCalc>run

D:\Temp\jni4net\samples\myCSharpDemoCalc>cd work
```

> D:\Temp\jni4net\samples\myCSharpDemoCalc\work>java -cp jni4net.j-
>   0.8.6.0.jar;MyCSharpDemoCalc.j4n.jar;. MyCalcUsageInJava Exception in thread "main" System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   D:\Temp\jni4net\samples\myCSharpDemoCalc\work\MyCSharpDemoCalc.j4n.dll
>   at net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFromClassLoader(File
>   assemblyFile, ClassLoader classLoader)    at
>   net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(File assemblyFile)
>   at net.sf.jni4net.__Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom3(IntPtr __envp,
>   JniLocalHandle __class, JniLocalHandle assemblyFile)
>           at net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(Native Method)
>           at MyCalcUsageInJava.main(MyCalcUsageInJava.java:11)

**Did anyone else have the same problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

csc: file `/nologo' does not exist

You must put the path of DotNet compiler (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 in my case) in your variable environemnet. And it works